Probability of hashing collisions
I'm trying to think of a follow-up to hashing collisions that goes like this:
Say we have a fixed set of (distinct) indices $\mathcal{J} \subset [d]$ where $|\mathcal{J}| = k$. Say I draw another index set $\mathcal{I}$ with $b$ uniform at random draws from $\{1, 2, ... d\}$. What is $\mathbb{E}[|\mathcal{I} \cap \mathcal{J}]|$?
For example, if $d = 4$, $k=3$, $b = 4$, we may have $\mathcal{J} = [1, 2, 3]$, $\mathcal{I} = [1, 1, 2, 4]$ and thus $|\mathcal{I} \cap \mathcal{J}| = 2$ because only 1, 2 intersect.

If I understand your question correctly, it seems like you can simply apply linearity of expectation.
For any $j \in \mathcal{J}$ let $A_j$ be the event that $j \in \mathcal{I}$, and $X_j$ be the corresponding indicator random variable, then:
$$
 \mathbb{E}[|\mathcal{J} \cap \mathcal{I}|] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j \in \mathcal{J}} X_j\right] = \sum_{j \in \mathcal{J}} \mathbb{E}[X_j] = \sum_{j \in \mathcal{J}} \Pr\left[{A}_j\right]= \sum_{j\in \mathcal{J}}\left(1-\Pr\left[\overline{A}_j\right]\right) = \sum_{j\in \mathcal{J}}\left(1-\left(1-{1\over d}\right)^b\right) = k \left(1-\left(1-{1\over d}\right)^b\right).
$$
